# Android Samsung FaceID Authentication SDK

Tags: java, android, authentication, biometrics

Where i can find SDK to support the FaceID Authentication or you guys has any source code for this feature ?

Google has no official announcement about that, it's supported on Samsung, on SamSung SDK i just found "Pass" for fingerprint.

Please suggest me which service do i use for FaceID on Samsung.

Comment: check this out https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.Face

Comment: i think the FaceDetector is use for face recognization in app , not authentication

Comment: Samsung may be waiting for official Android support: https://source.android.com/security/biometric

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource **are off-topic for Stack Overflow**. See details in [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).